# How to stop alert dialog from shifting upwards when keyboard is shown

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have ran into some issue with android. The situation is currently, when I tap the editText field in the alert dialog, the dialog will shift up to make way for the keyboard. However, I have calculated that there is enough space between my dialog and the keyboard. The reason behind is to have the dialog box hide the content that is underneath it.

**Question**

Is there a way to stop the alert dialog box from shifting upwards ?

Answer (score 0):

Add or change in `AndroidManifest.xml` for that activity tag.

```
<activity
        android:name=".YourActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing" />
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as you always need to show the keyboard immediately once the dialog opens rather than once a specific form widget inside gets focus (for instance, if your dialog just shows an EditText and a button), you can do the following:

```
    AlertDialog alertToShow = alert.create();
    alertToShow.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
    alertToShow.show();
```

Rather than calling .show() on your builder immediately, you can instead call .create() which allows you to do some extra processing on it before you display it onto the screen.

Answer (score 0):

To stop `AlertDialog` shifting up when software-keyboard shown, try this.

```
val dialog = MaterialDialogBuilder(context) // or AlertDialog.Builder(context)
    .setSomething() // setView, setListener, etc
    .create()
    .apply {
        with(window!!) {
            attributes = attributes.apply {
                type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_PANEL
            }
        }
     }
```